# Regex returns null for value if there is no match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use Regular Expressions to read a message that a user types, looks for keywords and count them up.

The issue I have is that if there is no match I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

I don't get that error if there is a match though it will count the amount of times the phrase is entered.

```
function readMessage() {
    var newtext = $("#myText").val()

    var newMessage = document.createElement("div");
    newMessage.setAttribute("id", "Divjuan");
    var messageText = document.createTextNode(newtext);
    console.log(messageText)
    newMessage.appendChild(messageText);

    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
    currentDiv.insertBefore(newMessage, currentDiv.childNode);

    var source1 = newtext;
    console.log(source1)
    var exampletcount1 = source1.match(/example1/g).length;
    console.log(exampletcount1)

    var exampletcount2 = source1.match(/example2/g).length;
    console.log(exampletcount2)

}
```

Any help would be great

Comment: You need to write your code to first check whether a match was found before you attempt to operate on the result with `.length`. For example, `var m = source1.match(/example1/g)` then check if `m` is not null (`if (m != null) ...`). If it isn't, then `m.length`, otherwise, don't do `m.length`. Pretty simple. :)

Comment: You accurately describe the behaviour of `String.match`. What's the question?

Comment: (what I'm trying to say is that your problem boils down to "how do I detect `null`" — and you seem to be aware of that — and this is a *very* complicated way to frame that question ; if on the other hand your post is meant to say "I wish `String.match` was more consistent", well, tough luck but SO is not a forum for complaining about the ECMAScript spec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
let count = (source1.match(/example1/g) || []).length
```

Here's a sample snippet:

```js
let source1 = "abcd";
console.log((source1.match(/example2/g) || []).length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether or not the match is null before attempting to access its length:

```
var examplematch1 = source1.match(/example1/g);
var exampletcount1 = examplematch1 ? examplematch1.length : 0;
console.log(exampletcount1);
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one, since it avoids the creation of a new Array object in the case where there are no matches in the source string, and remains just as clear in intent.